# Connect different machines with PoA

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, geth-debugging, peers, proof-of-authority

i want to connect two different machines in a ethereum private network!

I did it before with a normal PoW-Consesus but with PoA created by puppeth i cant see some Peers when i try:

```
admin.peers
```

Things i have done:

Initalize ethereum accounts on both machines with:

```
geth --datadir data/node1 account new
geth --datadir data/node2 account new
```

Then i created a genesis file with puppeth and copied it to the other machine that they are similiar!

The file looks like this:

> {
>     "config": {
>       "chainId": 1001,
>       "homesteadBlock": 1,
>       "eip150Block": 2,
>       "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
>       "eip155Block": 3,
>       "eip158Block": 3,
>       "byzantiumBlock": 4,
>       "constantinopleBlock": 5,
>       "clique": {
>         "period": 0,
>         "epoch": 30000
>       }
>     },
>     "nonce": "0x0",
>     "timestamp": "0x5c3894dc",
>     "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d460f5cc1dd0efec245ca8a87afd5c1ba1456f7e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
>     "gasLimit": "0x47b760",
>     "difficulty": "0x1",
>     "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
>     "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
>     "alloc": {
>       "d460f5cc1dd0efec245ca8a87afd5c1ba1456f7e": {
>         "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
>       }
>     },
>     "number": "0x0",
>     "gasUsed": "0x0",
>     "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

Then i initialized the genesis files with this commands:

```
geth --datadir data/node1/ init genesis.json
geth --datadir data/node2/ init genesis.json
```

After that i started both nodes with this commands:

```
geth --datadir="data/node1" --networkid "1001" --nodiscover console --unlock "d460f5cc1dd0efec245ca8a87afd5c1ba1456f7e" --rpc --rpcport "8000" --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,miner,debug,personal,rpc" --syncmode "full"

geth --datadir="data/node2" --networkid "1001" --nodiscover console --unlock "1200f5a866b0889a816d808a82b4f3be30ba6ba2" --rpc --rpcport "8000" --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,miner,debug,personal,rpc" --syncmode "full"
```

To find out the enode i wrote on the machine without prebalance:

```
admin.nodeInfo.enode
```

gives me this output:

> "enode://2c98ce532ae14020437889ecc9af8f15fd3463ccb6262c9eec124073ab6ee8999ebe2ff97bf8559e3b5b7c85157251129127600c955c1d1a3b3e9fb54330f120@127.0.0.1:30303?discport=0"

And executed this command on the main machine after copying the enode:

```
admin.addPeer("enode://2c98ce532ae14020437889ecc9af8f15fd3463ccb6262c9eec124073ab6ee8999ebe2ff97bf8559e3b5b7c85157251129127600c955c1d1a3b3e9fb54330f120@127.0.0.1:30303?discport=0")
```

i also tried this command:

```
admin.addPeer("enode://2c98ce532ae14020437889ecc9af8f15fd3463ccb6262c9eec124073ab6ee8999ebe2ff97bf8559e3b5b7c85157251129127600c955c1d1a3b3e9fb54330f120@127.0.0.1:30303")
```

Can u help me please to connect the peers of different machines that i can run a private PoA Ethereum!

Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to connect two machines you have to use their external ip not 127.0.0.1

For example if the ip is 192.168.1.99 then the command should be:

> admin.addPeer("enode://2c98ce532ae14020437889ecc9af8f15fd3463ccb6262c9eec124073ab6ee8999ebe2ff97bf8559e3b5b7c85157251129127600c955c1d1a3b3e9fb54330f120@**192.168.1.99**:30303")